# How to make index for R formula?

Tags: r, r-formula

I am trying to index some components in a R formula such like

```
var<-c("x1", "x2", "x3")

for (i in var) as.formula(i/x4)
```

But it always come with an error:

```
Error in i/x4 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

May somebody know how to make it work? so that out with,

```
x1/x4, x2/x4, x3/x4
```

Comment: Are you trying to make var into a formula, or a vector of numerics? Currently you have them declared as type character.

Comment: I am trying to index each component of var into separate formulas as assigned.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you're trying to do with the formulas? Are you just trying to compute these quotients (as I did in my answer) or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: I'm trying to use msm::deltamethod() function by index xs (x1,x2,x3...). But it seems your answer also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading OP's  comments, changing answer to OP's needs

```
for (i in var) {
        form <-sprintf("~ %s/ x4 ",i)
        deltamethod(as.formula(form),...) #other arguments that you need to supply
```

}

Comment: You're sticking x1 into sprintf instead of i.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! +1 (BTW, I'm not the one gave you the previous -1)

Answer (score 1):

Based on a comment from the OP it seems these formulas are meant to be used as the arguments to the `msm::deltamethod` function. From `?msm::deltamethod`, we read that an example formula would look like `~ 1 / (x1 + x2)`:

```
sapply(var, function(x) as.formula(paste0("~", x, "/x4")))
# $x1
# ~x1/x4
# <environment: 0x1016b07f0>
# 
# $x2
# ~x2/x4
# <environment: 0x1016a3ea0>
# 
# $x3
# ~x3/x4
# <environment: 0x101698630>
```

Now we have a list of formulas, each of which could be used as the first argument to `msm::deltamethod`.